# Populate Object with an Object in array of arrays with MongoDB + Node.js

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-populate

I want to populate an object in my Schema with an object inside array of arrays
So I need to check two IDs. One for each array.

```
{ _id: 101,
NewsGroup: [ [_id: 102, category: A], [_id: 103, category: B] ] }
```

I want to populate an object called Alpha with category: A

When I try this:

```
Model.findById(101).populate('Alpha', 'NewsGroup.category').exec(function(err, Beta) {
    req.Zita = Beta ;
    console.log( Zita );
});
```

It returns all categories Not only A.

I have tried this as well
But it does not work

```
.populate({
           path: 'Alpha',
           match: { 'NewsGroup':  { '_id': '102' } },
           //match: { 'NewsGroup':  { $elemMatch: { '_id': '102' }}  },
           select: 'category'
        })
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Hi Saeed, it seems like you have a lot of questions that you have asked here on SO that don't have any accepted answers. Can you please read [**What should I do when someone answers my question?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that you understand how things work around here and get better chances of having your questions answered by the community.

Comment: I know and I always do that But no one answer questions so that I can accept it or up vote it !!